# How to access iframe by id in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

How can I get reference of the iframe element with AngularJS ?

```
<div>
   <iframe id="myframe" ...>
</div>


mycontroller.$inject = ['$document'];

function mycontroller ($document) {
    console.log($document.getElementById("myframe")); //always null
}
```

I can see the iframe, but the reference lookup always prints null. Why?

Comment: Why you use angular for that? Call it from simple jquery :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$document` service returns an array.
You should use it like his :

```
console.log($document[0].getElementById("myframe"));
```

Please, see the jsfiddled solution : https://jsfiddle.net/jjbw1z8j/2/

Answer (score 1):

use this,

```
angular.element('#myframe');
```

or

```
console.log(angular.element('#myframe'));
```

Answer (score -2):

In **angular** interaction with the **DOM** elements should be implemented in the **directives**.

For example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/znmzj1za/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {

  })
  .directive('myFrame', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elem) {
        console.log('it`s your iframe', elem);
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div>
      <iframe my-frame></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because it is not the answer for the question